# How to create key-value in a multi array?

Tags: swift2

I created array like this:

```
var locale : [String : [String : [String : String]]] = [:]
```

I want to check if a value exists, and create it if it doesn't:

```
if locale["10333"]?["12000"]?["message"] == nil {
    //create one
    locale["10333"]!["12000"]!["message"] = "hey test"
}
```

My error says:

> **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

How can I create the KEY `locale[KEY][KEY][KEY] = VALUE`?

Can someone give me a little hint?

Comment: A few hints: What do you think that error message means? What will `locale["10333"]!` do if `locale` doesn't have a value for `10333`? Can you think of a way to write safer code without using any `!` operators?

Comment: if i have `locale["10333"]["12000"]["message"] = "hey test"`my error is `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String : String]]?' with an index of type 'String'` and i am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `locale["10333"]` is nil, or `locale["10333"]!["12000"]` is nil. 
In this case accessing `locale["10333"]!["12000"]!` will generate the fatal error you are receiving.

You must check for nil and initialise as needed any dictionary value, not only the last one.

Comment: Yes is nil if i check a first time and after this i would like add key and value. Why is so complicated in swift ? how can i initialise ?

Comment: @user4347073 You need to set `locale["10333"]` to something before you set `locale["10333"]!["12000"]`, and you need to set `locale["10333"]!["12000"]` to something before you set `locale["10333"]!["12000"]!["message"]`.

Comment: I thought is auto set when i try create not exist key. BTW thanks i ill try